# Google Sheets, view two sheets side by side

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Sheets, I have a `Results` main sheet, and the `Details` sheet.

I would like to modify the `Details` and see the `Results` changing.

Is it possible to split the view between two sheets in the same browser window?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot split the view between two sheets in the same browser window.

As a workaround though, you can use `INDEX` and place the content of the ranges you need from `Results` to columns next to your content in your `Details`

*(This is just one way. There are more depending on the situation.)*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In (Ubuntu) Linux using the Gnome extension `Shell Tile` it would be possible to show two (or more) instances of Google Sheets with the separate, individual tabs displayed in each tile to achieve this effect. As for Windows, I can't be certain.

[image]

This produces this effect - two separate tabs selected, same Google Sheet

[image]

Comment: OP asks "the same browser window". Thanks

Comment: @Serge but this is still a valid solution for those who can exploit it. Moreover, it doesn't alter the structure of the main sheet or detail sheet.

Comment: @User24610 maybe, but my idea was to let users that has the viewer shared link to the file see the both sheets at the same time...

Comment: @Serge That requirement wasn't clear in your question.